# Why aren't my CSS3 media queries working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, media-queries

Need your help. Can't solve this down, been looking for the answer for so long and didn't find anything on it.

It's about a simple media query written abslutely correct.

```
@media (max-width: 942px) {
.top-header {
    flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

Besides, I don't see the "flex-direction: column" style applied to the ".top-header" in  Web Inspector somehow.

Using preprocessor LESS and koala compiler, just so you know. Don't get any errors from the compiler, the generated CSS file is ok: that media query code is there, right at the end of the file as it has to be.

Media viewport is used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here is an HTML snippet, where the ".top-header" can be found:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top-header">
            <div class="top-header__logo">
                <img src="img/Welcome-page/header/Logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
    ...
</header>
```

There you can see that name class ".top-header", so what couid it be...

So really can't figure it out, hoping to get some straight answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Nick! The StackOverflow editor has a nifty feature called "snippets". Please edit your question to use a snippet, that contains a simple reproducible example, that we can then analyse. Or "what Derek said" :-)

Comment: Give us an sample of usage the selector in your html. Open inspector mode in your browser and make sure that there is no other styles which override the flex-direction or display: flex.

Comment: It's more likely that the media query is fine, but your HTML isn't set up for the style you are applying to it or that you have another style that is more specific than the media query. A simple test would be to set the `background-color` of something in the media query and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah other than the missing `}` at the end that looks like valid CSS.

Comment: Guys, it's not about the missing "}" (I have this thing put in my media query file, I just forgot to place it in that code sample for some reason). So the query is fine, it has to do with something else. I'm not sure about overriding or styles specification, but when I tried to replace that "flex-direction: column" code with "background-color: red" (for example), it still didn't work. I mean whatever I put instead of that piece of media query code, it's not responding.

Comment: You don't put what the expected behavior is in your question. What do you expect to happen? If you open up your web inspector can you see the style applied? Does `.top-header` element exist in your markup? Post your html here too. Without it, we can't help much.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle with your code as written above working](https://jsfiddle.net/pk4r2tgq/). There is something else going on in your other code that you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead:

```html
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
```

Also, your media query has a missing }

Comment: Tried to paste your code above - didn't work. And honestly I have no idea why I didn't put that } at the end of the media query in that code sample, because I have this "}" put in my media query css file, so it's not the answer(